# jQuery Data Table Headers Not Aligned With Rows When In Bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-tabs

For some reason on my site my jQuery Data Table's column headers are not aligning up with the rows.

Here is an example:
[image]
Please note that some of my tables (the above one included) are inside Bootstrap tabs. I believe this is the cause because when they are not in a tab they display just fine.

I know that bootstrap considers data in other tabs 'not visible' so I think it is related to that.

Does anybody have a simple css or js fix? Thanks in advance.

**Edit, here is some code:**

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="<?php echo $tab_1; ?>"><a href="#activeusers"  class="tab-nonwhitetext" aria-controls="activeusers" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Active Users</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="<?php echo $tab_2; ?>"><a href="#inactiveusers"  class="tab-nonwhitetext" aria-controls="inactiveusers" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Inactive Users</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php echo $tab_1; ?>" id="activeusers">
        <?php echo $table1; ?>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php echo $tab_2; ?>" id="inactiveusers">
        <?php echo $table2; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<table "border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="20" class="display dataTable new-table-styling dynamic-table" id="table" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Job Title/Education</th><th>Room/Phone(s)</th><th>Email/Supervisor</th><th>Employee Type</th><th>Image</th><th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could you provide link to your site? or a fiddle where we can see what is causing this issue

Comment: We need to see the HTML that is generated by $table1 and $table2

Comment: That didn't give us the html of the tables. You may need to get the source code of your page after it is rendered and paste it in.

Comment: Which dataTables js files are you including in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page has the js and css files needed for [DataTables w/ Bootstrap](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap).  If `dataTables.bootstrap.js` (and the associated `dataTables.bootstrap.css`) are not included, your table won't render correctly.

> The main DataTables file has the name jquery.dataTables.js using the format that is common to the majority of jQuery plug-ins. There is also a styling integration file for the various styling libraries supported by DataTables, this has the format `dataTables.{style}.js` (`dataTables.bootstrap.js` for Bootstrap for example).
>
> Both of these Javascript files should be included - the main file to include the basic DataTables functionality and the styling file to set defaults as appropriate for the styling library.
>
> For CSS only a single file should be included as the styling library will provide the core styling options for the table. The CSS files have the format `dataTables.{style}.css` (`dataTables.bootstrap.css` for Bootstrap for example).